# Subscribe twice to Angular 11 http?

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient, subscribe

I am a beginner in angular and I have encountered a very difficult problem. That is when I subscribe, two requests will be generated. I am sure that there is no problem with the backend, because I set a breakpoint and requested with postman. The breakpoint indicated that it was sent once, but the request with the angular customer service terminal was sent twice. I will be grateful if anyone can tell me the answer.

dialog.component.html

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="add()">
  <h5 mat-dialog-title>Add</h5>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <mat-label>name:</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="value" formControlName="name">
      <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button (click)="value=''">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <mat-label>description</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput placeholder="" formControlName="description"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>cancel</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ListService } from '../list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  value = '';
  addForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private lisitService: ListService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.required],
      'description': ['']
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  add() {
    this.lisitService.add(this.addForm.value).subscribe(result => {
      console.log("函数执行了");
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

list.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListService {

  private getPath: string;
  private addPath: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.getPath = baseUrl + 'documents/html/tags/get';
    this.addPath = baseUrl + 'documents/html/tags/add';
  }

  add(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.addPath, data);
  }
}
```

[frist:200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dnGd.png)

[second:500 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint, I know.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjgyH.png)

Comment: Try adding unsubscribe on ng destroy method.

Comment: Getting back 500 means you also have a server error. I can't see anything in your code that should call add twice. Basically fix your server first.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha
 First of all, thank you very much for answering my question in your busy schedule. Maybe I didn't describe the problem clearly. I followed your instructions, but still the same problem. Oh, I forgot to say that my component was not destroyed after the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem of submitting two requests at once has been resolved
The reason is that what the backend returns is not a json object but a string, and the frontend receives the default json object, so I think the reason lies here, and the problem is solved after the modification.**

I made the following changes in the backend

**Function**

```
        public async Task<AddTagResponseModel> Add(string name, string description)
        {
            var tag = new Tag
            {
                Name = name,
                Description = description
            };

            this.data.Add(tag);

            await this.data.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new AddTagResponseModel
            {
                Result = "添加成功"
            };
        }
```

**AddTagResponseModel**

```
namespace www.wuxiancong.com.Features.Documents.Html.Tags.Models
{
    public class AddTagResponseModel
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The front end has been modified as follows.
**[The requested data received by default is Json]**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DocumentsHtmlTagsListService } from '../list.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  value = '';
  addForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private lisitService: DocumentsHtmlTagsListService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.required],
      'description': ['']
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  add() {
    var obs = this.lisitService.add(this.addForm.value).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data['result']);
    });
  }
}
```

**I made a low-level mistake, which troubled me for three days.**